# Is there free and good line-level profiler for PHP?

Tags: php, profiler

Is there free and good line-level profiler for PHP? I'm using xdebug and it's relatively good but it gives me function level output and sometimes it's hard to see where exactly all the time spent in the function goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not free, but the [SD PHP Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html) provides information about the relative costs of each block of PHP code, not just functions:

Comment: I can't think of a more complicated interface :)

Comment: tried to follow this suggestion.  the evaluation copy is so crippled as to be useless -- 3 code files of no more than 1000 lines each...

the programs rely on environment variables and the installer doesn't install them correctly -- why not just write out a config file...?

really frustrating because the output looks really good in the screenshot, it's just wrapped around a very difficult UI.  many languages supported, but only one developer-perspective paradigm taken into account as far as UI goes.

Comment: @gazarsgo: The environment variables are, as far as we know, installed correctly. We'd be happy(?) to accept feedback telling us which OS version you used, and why you think the environment variables are wrong. More recent versions of Windows require you to log out and log back in for environment variable settings to take effect (thanks for that, Microsoft). Did you try running the example?

Answer (score 1):

Zend Platform will give you some more precise profiling information. Its that or using webgrind and zend studio / Eclipse profiler for you performance information.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a microtime() and it suits me well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such profiler.
If possible, a workaround could be to split long functions that are identified to be bottleneck to smaller functions. Not only that's good programming practice (although not always easy to enforce, I reckon), but it might allow to pinpoint more precisely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is [bytekit](http://www.bytekit.org/), which is an opcode disassembler. That will give you a detailed view of what is going on. Alternatively, you can use C-level debugger such as [gdb](http://derickrethans.nl/phps_segmentation_faults_gdbfu.php). This gives you an even closer look, since you can debug in to C-level functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively sure I got line-level output with Xdebug and KCacheGrind. Could've been it reported it for those lines with function calls based on how long that function took, but in any case.

Comment: No, it can show you source code and info about how much time function called from this line took. But it doesn't help with lines where only language constructions are used.